# Cassandra connections - Shared 'Cluster' instance or multiple?

Tags: java, concurrency, cassandra, connection

When using the [Cassandra driver](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.datastax.cassandra/cassandra-driver-core/2.1.4) within a Java project, what is the best practice for managing connections?  Specifically with respect to whether it's better practice to allow multiple threads to share a single `Cluster` instance or to allocate a separate `Cluster` instance for each thread that needs to talk to Cassandra.

I followed the [example code](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/1.0/java-driver/quick_start/qsSimpleClientCreate_t.html) and am setting up my `Cluster` instance like:

```
Cluster.builder().addContactPoint(HOST).withPort(PORT)
    .withCredentials(USER, PASS).build();
```

So what I'm asking is would the preferred approach be to do something like this (single shared `Cluster` instance):

```
private static Cluster _cluster = null;

public static Cluster connect() {
    if (_cluster != null && ! _cluster.isClosed()) {
        //return the cached instance
        return _cluster;
    }

    //create a new instance
    _cluster = Cluster.builder().addContactPoint(HOST).withPort(PORT)
                .withCredentials(USER, PASS).build();
    return _cluster;
}
```

...or is it best practice to return multiple `Cluster` instances?  Like so:

```
public static Cluster connect() {
    //every caller gets their own Cluster instance
    return Cluster.builder().addContactPoint(HOST).withPort(PORT)
                .withCredentials(USER, PASS).build();
}
```

I guess the points at the core of this question are:

- Is building a new `Cluster` instance an expensive operation?
- Will the `Cluster` object internally manage/pool connections to the backing datastore, or does it function more like an abstraction of a single connection?
- Is the `Cluster` object thread-safe?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is building a new Cluster instance an expensive operation?

Calling build to construct a Cluster instance does no networking IO, so it is a non-expensive operation.

> Will the Cluster object internally manage/pool connections to the backing datastore, or does it function more like an abstraction of a single connection?

What is expensive is calling `cluster.init()` which creates a single connection (control connection) to one of your contact points.   `cluster.connect()` is even more expensive since it inits the Cluster (if it hasn't been already) and creates a [`Session`](http://docs.datastax.com/en/drivers/java/2.1/com/datastax/driver/core/Session.html) which manages a connection pool (with pool size based on your [PoolingOptions](http://docs.datastax.com/en/drivers/java/2.1/com/datastax/driver/core/PoolingOptions.html)) to each discovered host.  So yes, a `Cluster` has a 'control connection' to manage the state of hosts and each `Session` created via `Cluster.connect()` will have a connection pool to each host.

> Is the Cluster object thread-safe?

Put simply, yes :)

[4 simple rules when using the DataStax drivers for Cassandra](http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/4-simple-rules-when-using-the-datastax-drivers-for-cassandra) provides further guidance on this topic.

Comment: Thanks, that's a good reference.  In case that link ever dies, part of what it says is "Basically you will want to share the same cluster and session instances across your application".

Comment: Thanks for including that.  That is a key point I missed (Share cluster and session instances), +1!